# `this.getView().byId` with ID created in the controller returns `undefined`

Tags: sapui5

I have a UI5 app constructed from `index.html`. I insert the app at body like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script>
      sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
        new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
          name: "cvg.myApp"
        }).placeAt("content");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCozy" id="content"></body>
</html>
```

Then in the `main.view.xml`, I create a basic MVC view with an empty splitter.

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="cvg.myApp.controller.main"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout">
  <layout:Splitter id="splitter" height="100vh" orientation="Horizontal">
    <!-- ... -->
  </layout:Splitter>
</mvc:View>
```

Now, in the main controller `onInit` among other things, I try to insert content areas to my splitter.

```js
var tableSettings = {
  entitySet: "projectSet",
  tableType: "ResponsiveTable",
  useExportToExcel: true,
};
var leftTable = new sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable("taskTable", tableSettings);
var rightTable = new sap.m.HBox("dataView", {});
var oSplitter = this.getView().byId("splitter");
oSplitter.insertContentArea(rightTable, 0);
oSplitter.insertContentArea(leftTable, 0)
```

Now I try to access the content areas and assign a model (previously defined) specifically to the `"taskTable"`, but the control with the ID `"taskTable"` is not accessible:

```js
var oTaskTable = this.getView().byId("taskTable"); // returns: undefined
oTaskTable.setModel(taskModel);
```

`oTaskTable` remains undefined.

Comment: Replace `"taskTable"` with `this.createId("taskTable")` when creating the SmartTable. By doing so, the control will be accessible via `this.byId` (or `this.getView().byId`) as mentioned in the linked answer above.